# Align hint text in multiline TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, textfield

I have a multiline TextField with a prefixIcon, so now the Icon is in the center vertically and hint text is at top left. I want both of them to be aligned, either at the top or in the center vertically.

[image]

The code used is

```
    Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
          child: TextField(
            maxLines: 3,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Bio',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.chrome_reader_mode),
              fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
              filled: true,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Try wrap the `TextField` in a `Column` Widget and use the `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` property

Comment: Tried! It didn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ugly solution, but it works. Other solutions (e.g., setting the `textAlignVertical` to `TextAlignVertical.center`) don't work since the **`maxLines` is not null**.

Add a `TextStyle` to the `hintText` and set the `height` of the `TextStyle` to `2.8`. You need to reduce this when the `fontSize` is bigger because the `height` will be multiplied by the `fontSize` to make the line height. I added a `contentPadding` to make sure the text doesn't overflow(because now the text begins from the center of the `TextField`).

```
TextField(
                    maxLines: 3,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
                      hintText: 'Bio',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        height: 2.8,
                      ),
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.chrome_reader_mode),
                      fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                      filled: true,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Result:

[image: res]

Answer (score 4):

Although in your particular case problem can be solved by adding a newline character (`hintText: '\nBio'`), a better solution is to use `labelText` property instead of a `hintText`. By default label is aligned with the center of the TextField.

```dart
      TextField(
        maxLines: 3,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Bio',
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.chrome_reader_mode),
          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
          filled: true,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            borderSide: BorderSide(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: The labelText instead of hintText works fine, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
  Widget customTextView(String hint, Icon iconName) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: _DarkWhiteColor.withOpacity(0.5),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0),
        child: TextField(
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
          cursorColor: Colors.grey,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            fillColor: _DarkWhiteColor.withOpacity(0),
            filled: true,
            hintText: "Enter Your Message",
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
//                suffixIcon: iconName,
            prefixIcon: Container(
              transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, -45, 0),
              child: iconName,
            ),
          ),
          maxLines: 6,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: you need to use icon in decoration and also use

            prefixIcon: Container(
              transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, -45, 0),
              child: iconName,
            ),

Answer (score 0):

Set minLines to 1.

```
TextField(textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                            minLines: 1,
                            maxLines: 3,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Bio',
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.email),
                              fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                              filled: true,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```